# Deserialize javascript objects to generic list in c# handler

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

Im creating some javascript items in a loop

```
var licenseList = {};

$($licenses).each(function (index) {

                var license = {};
                var editedValues = {};

                license.PRODUCT_KEY = $(this).parent('div.licensewrapper').data('productkey');

                $(this).find('input:text').each(function (i, val) {

                    if ($(val).attr('data-default-value') != $(val).val() && $(val).val() > 0 && $(val).data('isValid') != false) {

                        var pogKey = $(val).data('product_option_group_key');
                        var editedValue = $(val).val();

                        editedValues[pogKey] = editedValue;

                        license.editedValues = editedValues;

                    }

                });

    //licenseList[index] = license;
    //liceneList.push(license); //if array...
});
```

I've commented out my current solutions. But i dont think any of the two are equal to a generic list when derelializing them in c#. Whats the corrent way to do it in this case? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create your array

```
var licenseList = [];
```

for each of your licenses...

```
var license = {
    prop1: 'p1',
    prop2: 'p2'
};
licenseList.push(license);
```

format and serialize JSON data to be sent over to webmethod

```
data = {
    LicenseList: licenseList
};

$.ajax({
      ...
      data: JSON.stringify(data)
      ...
      });
```

in your webmethod your method parameter must match

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetLicenses(List<License> LicenseList)
{
   foreach(var license in LicenseList)
   {
     // do whatever
   }
}
```

sample license class. Your properties need to match with your objects in your javascript

```
public class License
{
   public string Prop1 {get; set;}
   public string Prop2 {get; set;}
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yea i suppose this is the best way then. Btw, the properties doesnt need to match, but if they do, they get mapped to the c# object automatically.

Comment: yes you are right, i should have said in order to retrieve the values correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
  function sendToServer(licenseList)
  {
  var url = "controller.ashx";
  var data = {};
  data.SerializedObj = JSON.stringify(licenseList);
   $.post(url, data, function(response){
    if(response.length > 0)
    {
        alert(response);
    }
   });
  }

  //controller.ashx :
  public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
  //...
  string serializedObj = context.Request.Form["SerializedObj"] ?? "";
  JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
  List<license> collection = js.Deserialize<List<license>>(serializedObj);

  //...
  public class license
  {
  public  string Propertie1 {get;set;}
  public  string Propertie2 {get;set;}
  }
```

Javascript object must have the same properties:

```
var license = {Propertie1 : 'value1', Propertie2 : 'value2'};
```